# How to build x86 and/or x64 on Windows from command line with CMAKE?

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmake, cross-compiling, x86-64

One way to get cmake to build x86 on Windows with Visual Studio is like so:

1. Start Visual Studio Command prompt for x86
2. Run cmake: `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" \path_to_source\`
3. nmake

One way to get cmake to build x64 on Windows with Visual Studio is like so:

1. Start Visual Studio Command prompt for x64
2. Run cmake: `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" \path_to_source\`
3. nmake

Using Cmake, how do I compile either or both architectures? (like how Visual Studio does it from in the IDE)

Comment: Same here, but there seems to be a solution: http://zeroset.mnim.org/2015/07/15/building-visual-studio-x86-and-x64-binaries-with-cmake-nmake-and-qt-creator/ (and that without closing the prompt, and using `nmake`)

Comment: If you arrived here because you are using `-G"Ninja"` as a generator on windows; to build **32bit** use **"x86 Native Tools Command Prompt"** and to build 64bit use "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" it will use the correct libs, compiler and linker.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

This cannot be done with CMake. You have to generate two separate build folders. One for the x86 NMake build and one for the x64 NMake build. You cannot generate a single Visual Studio project covering both architectures with CMake, either.

To build Visual Studio projects from the command line for both 32-bit and 64-bit without starting a Visual Studio command prompt, use the regular Visual Studio generators.

For CMake 3.13 or newer, run the following commands:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A Win32 -S \path_to_source\ -B "build32"
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -S \path_to_source\ -B "build64"
cmake --build build32 --config Release
cmake --build build64 --config Release
```

For earlier versions of CMake, run the following commands:

```
mkdir build32 & pushd build32
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" \path_to_source\
popd
mkdir build64 & pushd build64
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" \path_to_source\
popd
cmake --build build32 --config Release
cmake --build build64 --config Release
```

CMake generated projects that use one of the Visual Studio generators can be built from the command line with using the option `--build` followed by the build directory. The `--config` option specifies the build configuration.

Comment: Is there a way to use one command prompt + two build directories, and make both architectures without having to exit and start the x86 prompt, then the x64 prompt?

Answer (score 83):

try use `CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM`

e.g.

```
// x86
cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x86 . 

// x64
cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 .
```

Comment: simple yet portable!

Comment: use `Win32` and `Win64` instead of `x86` and `x64` for visual studio 2019

Comment: @maidamai I believe it is `Win32` and `x64` for VS 16 2019 https://stackoverflow.com/a/58548724/3554391

Answer (score 40):

Besides `CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM` variable, there is also the `-A` switch

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html#platform-selection

```
  -A <platform-name>           = Specify platform name if supported by
                                 generator.
```