# cmake windows x64 builds

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

Is there a way to use the cmake gui to specify a x64 build, since by default cmake on windows creates a 32-bit Visual Studio solution.

From the command line, folks say to do this:

C:\projectx\build> cmake ..\make -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64"

but how do I get to the command line arguments from the cmake windows gui?

see:

http://www.saoe.net/blog/778/

[How to build x86 and/or x64 on Windows from command line with CMAKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350214/how-to-build-x86-and-or-x64-on-windows-from-command-line-with-cmake)

[cmake -G Ninja on windows specify x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262342/cmake-g-ninja-on-windows-specify-x64)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found to do this, is to wipe the output folder, and then it lets you select **Visual Studio 10 Win64** when you first configure the cmake project. Make sure you choose the correct item in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it during the first configure process.

After that, if you want to change the machine type you need to delete the cache with the "Delete Cache" command in the "File" menu and start the configure process again.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you run cmake in a `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` for the first time (otherwise delete build folder).