# CMake is adding /machine:X86 to linker

Tags: c++, cmake, 64-bit

I am learning how to use CMake by building an existing project that is normally built in Visual Studio

I will post the CMakeLists.txt below

I am building using the `VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`

The build commands are:

`cmake .. -G"Nmake Makefiles"`
`nmake`

The error I get during linking stage:

```
...
[  3%] Linking CXX executable SimManager.exe
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1425~1.286\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\SimManager.dir\objects1.rsp /out:SimManager.exe /implib:SimManager.lib /pdb:E:\Projects\SimManager\Debug\SimManager.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console d3dcompiler.lib ../lib/d3dx11.lib dxgi.lib d3d11.lib dinput8.lib dxguid.lib ../lib/DirectXTex.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\SimManager.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\SimManager.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1112) with the following output:
msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I dont understand why its adding the `/machine:X86` flag to the linker command line,
This is not specified anywhere in the CMakeLists.txt file

I can see that the flags I set in CMakeLists.txt to `machine:X64` are `machine:X86` in CMakeCache.txt. Why is this?

For example

```
Line 71: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86
Line 121: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86
Line 148: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86
```

How can I change that flag to `/machine:X64`
What other things are visibly wrong with the CMakeLists.txt?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.0)

project(SimManager CXX)


ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR AMD64)
set(ARCH amd64)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS machine:X64)
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS machine:X64)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS machine:X64)
set(DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)

add_executable(SimManager 
    Source/ProgramBuilder.cpp
    Source/FileSystem/PathBuilder.cpp
    )

set_target_properties (${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE
    CXX_EXTENSIONS FALSE
    )

set (D3D11_FOUND "YES")
set (D3D11_LIBRARIES ${D3D11_LIB})
mark_as_advanced (D3D11_INCLUDE_PATH D3D11_LIB)

add_library(d3dx11.lib STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(DirectXTex.lib STATIC IMPORTED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} d3dcompiler)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ../lib/d3dx11)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} dxgi)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} d3d11)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} dinput8)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} dxguid)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ../lib/DirectXTex)
```

CmakeCache.txt:

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: e:/Projects/SimManager/Debug
# It was generated by CMake: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo
// MinSizeRel ...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/MD /O1 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C++ applications.
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib

//Flags used by the linker during all build types.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/SimManager

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx86/x86/link.exe

//Program used to build from makefiles.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:STRING=nmake

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// all build types.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MT:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x86/mt.exe

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=SimManager

//RC compiler
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x86/rc.exe

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS:STRING=-DWIN32

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-D_DEBUG

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE

//Value Computed by CMake
SimManager_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=E:/Projects/SimManager/Debug

//Value Computed by CMake
SimManager_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=E:/Projects/SimManager


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=e:/Projects/SimManager/Debug
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=17
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=0
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cpack.exe
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/ctest.exe
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to cache edit program executable.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake-gui.exe
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=Unknown
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=NMake Makefiles
//Generator instance identifier.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=E:/Projects/SimManager
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MT
CMAKE_MT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER_WORKS:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

Comment: Have You tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846043/1150918 ?
`cmake -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 .. `

Comment: It sounds like this may be a stale configuration from an older build you may have done in the same folder. Be sure you remove your build folder and re-run CMake from scratch. Also, if the issue persists, you can try setting the architecture in the `cmake` command line: `cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 ..`

Comment: "cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 .."

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (project):
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!