# С++ array size is uint32 or uint64

Tags: c++, memory-management, cmake, cl

I used to write my code with JB Rider and compile it with VS native C++ compiler (CL). A few days ago I decided to use JB CLion with CMake. I thought that it should use my native compiler as well, so no differences should appear.

***However***

I have some code

```
uint64 size = get_some_size();
byte* buffer = new byte[size];
```

This code compiles without warnings in Rider, but when I run build with CMake I get:

```
warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'uint64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

It seems like CMake build force arrays to have size in `unsigned int32`. Why and how to fix that?

Comment: CMake doesn't build anything ... That's the compiler. Are you building in 32-bit by mistake?

Comment: If you build for 32 bit subsystem of windows then of course array size is 32 bit.

Comment: @ChrisMM Probably, yes. How can I tell it to build exactly in 64-bit?

Comment: Check the options of the compiler you are using, it should have a way to specify the target architecture.

Comment: [How to build x86 and/or x64 on Windows from command line with CMAKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350214/how-to-build-x86-and-or-x64-on-windows-from-command-line-with-cmake) - you can run it with `-A x64`

Comment: If using `GCC` or `CLANG` as the compiler, you can do `-m32` or `-m64` in the `target_compile_options`

Comment: Thank you, it helped :) With CLion I had to open `File->Settings->...->Toolchains` and in "Visual Studio" toolchain set "Architecture" to "x64" (if unset, it use x86)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build x86 and/or x64 on Windows from command line with CMAKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350214/how-to-build-x86-and-or-x64-on-windows-from-command-line-with-cmake)

Comment: While I realise the question is about how to build in 64-bit rather than 32-bit, why are you using `uint64` instead of `size_t` to represent array sizes?

Comment: @starball later yes, but initial question was  about why I'm getting warnings about `uint64` being an array size

Comment: @Peter good comment, I'll probably change that later. I never compiled a code on 32-bit architecture so I didn't knew that it also affects an array size type, I knew only about pointer type